# Symfony 3.4 Form widget prefix the id with bundle name

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-3.4

I'm using Symfony 3.4 for a project, in the FormType based on an entity that is related to others entities and those FormTypes based on entities from other bundles are added to get a form collection. The problem here is that i'm have an js file that i can't modify, and this file applies a listener over an input with an specific id, "date_campana" to be more specific, but when i render the form widget, the system prefix the assigned id with the Bundle name, the result is id="campanabundle_date_campana" i need avoid the prefixing of this specific field.

My code is:

CampanaType.php

```
->add('fecha',TextType::class,
    [
        'attr' => [
            'id'=>'campana_fecha',
            'data-start'=>2, //TODO: Parametrizable desde SystemBundle
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'data-content' => 'Seleccione el/los Productos de interés de su oferta y programe el envío de la misma en una fecha disponible <strong> Seleccione una fecha posterior a 3 días de la fecha actual.</strong>',
            'data-placement' => 'top',
            'data-trigger' => 'hover',
            'data-toggle' => 'popover',
            'data-html' => 'true',
        ]
    ]
)
```

new.html.twig

```
{{ form_widget(form.fecha, { 'attr': {'id': 'campana_fecha'}}) }}
```

But, nothing of those works, the id still beign prefixed with campanabundle_ string breaking the js file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you're trying to achieve is exactly possible in Symfony 3.4, see here https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/20965#issuecomment-267674782.

You could try overriding the default prefixed id with:

```
public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
{
    $view->vars['id'] = '"date_campana';
}
```

Don't forget then to remove the id from the attr array.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, can't you use an attribute like

`'data-id' => 'campana_fecha'`

or a class

`'class' => 'form-control campana_fecha'`?

If you use a class, then you can use `getElementsByClassName('campana_fecha')[0]` instead of `getElementById('campana_fecha')` in javascript

Comment: The javascript that i can't edit, search the element only by exact id.

Comment: I can't think of any way to achieve this without removing the prefix for the whole form, or using another attribute, otherwise you might break the form when processed by the framework